# Bootstrap menu with menu items go to submenus when not enough space

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap. I have been searching on google with no luck.. probably 
because I dont know how to search it.

This is the basic example that i'm checking

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I just want a main menu but instead of a navbar-toggler when the device width is small i would like the toogle but with the items that dissapeared because there is not enough space...

Something like (sorry about the picture, done with paint but it is easier to see):

[image: Sorry about the picture, done with paint :P]

is that possible?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear or you can push the code to codepen so that we can view it

Comment: I have added a picture @odinakajoy

Comment: Is possible but will take more code. Why not just put all link under the mobile menu icon except the logo or home page? That's easier

Comment: It is not about what is easy , it is about what I want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyWebsite</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Hello World</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: In your solution all the menus go to the toogler menu when you go under a certain width, i just want the one that doesnt fit in the main bar, the rest in the main bar.